# newSingleThreadContext() causes outofmemoryexeception in my service on Android

Tags: kotlin, thread-safety, out-of-memory, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am using `*newSingleThreadContext()*` to create a work and a arch threads. And I get outofmemory exception. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSVey.png)

Here is the code : "sampleId" is called everytime we change a parameter and this is implemented to throttle spamming of parameters to a test-library. Where we execute parameters sequentially instead of parallel.

```
package com.my.app.extension

import com.my.app.datastore.ParamValue
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Mutex
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.withLock


suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.waitForTrue(stateFlow: StateFlow<Boolean>): Flow<T> {
    return flow {
        stateFlow.first { it }
        this@waitForTrue.collect(this)
    }
}

/**
 * Sample unique id and only return after a waiting time defined
 * @param periodMillis The time we wait to return if we get lots of calls in ms
 * @param waitMillis The time before next execution in ms
 */
@DelicateCoroutinesApi
fun Flow<Pair<String, ParamValue?>>.sampleId(
    periodMillis: Long,
    waitMillis: Long = 100
): Flow<Pair<String, ParamValue?>> =
    channelFlow {
        val hashMap = hashMapOf<Int, HashMap<String, Pair<String, ParamValue?>>>()
        var hasBeenActivated = false
        var activated = false
        var task: Deferred<Unit>? = null
        val mutex = Mutex()

        fun process() {
            if (!hasBeenActivated) {
                hasBeenActivated = true
                launch(newSingleThreadContext("work")) {
                    while (activated) {
                        delay(periodMillis)
                        mutex.withLock {
                            // hashmap operations.
                        }
                    }
                    hasBeenActivated = false
                }
            }
        }

        launch(newSingleThreadContext("arch")) {
            collect { item ->
                activated = true
                task?.cancel()
                task = async {
                    delay(waitMillis)
                    activated = false
                }
                mutex.withLock {
                    item.second?.let {
                        // hashmap operations.
                    }
                }
                process()
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to use different APIs of kotlin-android like `newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher(),` also used "use" call to free up the resource used like this

```
val context = newSingleThreadContext("worker")
                    context.use {
                        launch(context) {
```

But for some reason those parameter updates are not sent to the test-library at all.

I need somekind of mechanism where I do not get this outofmemory exception(by releasing threads after each iteration or something) and also the parameter updates are sent to the test-library.

Comment: Have you looked at [api documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/new-single-thread-context.html) ? `newSingleThreadContext(name: String)` returns a **closeable** object. You are responsible for closing it, to release associated resources. P.S: Please include the error trace as preformated text, not as image.